# sql combine 2 queries with JOIN

Tags: sql, join

I know it's not a good idea to loop SQL queries, so I would like to change these two queries into one.

Not being too great at JOINs, I'm struggling to figure how to merge these two, with it having that DISTINCT in there.

```
$sql_result2 = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT gang FROM turfs WHERE city='$city'", $db);  
while ($rs2 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result2)) {

    $sql_result3 = mysql_query("SELECT (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM turfs WHERE city='$city' AND gang=g.id) as count, g.id, g.name, g.color FROM gangs g WHERE g.id='$rs2[gang]'", $db); 
    $rs3 = mysql_fetch_array($sql_result3);
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: **WARNING** your code is susceptible to sql injection attacks

Comment: the `'$city'` is mysql_escaped before this query

Comment: i wasn't aware of that, but this is a common practice of mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join and group with something like:

```
select   count(*) as count, G.ID, G.NAME, G.COLOR
from     GANGS G join TURFS T on T.GANG = G.ID
where    CITY = '$city'
group by G.ID, G.NAME, G.COLOR
```